# drupal translation t() function doesn't do anything...outputs the same text

Tags: drupal, internationalization

I've read that using the `t('text to translate')` I can translate texts in drupal templates.  The problem is, this function doesn't do anything. It simply outputs the same text.

I already have a site and I have installed the proper modules so that's not the problem.

I am using this to translate the titles for the blocks in block.tpl.php.

```
<h2><?php print t($block->subject); ?></h2>
```

So this outputs the same original text i'm defining in the title of the view as the block. Why? If I had an error shouldn't Drupal output something or log that error at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation is not magic. You also need to set up the language of your site in something else than english and be sure that the string you display have a translation.

You can check this at this page : `exemple.com/?q=admin/build/translate/search` (d6 url)

Comment: it would be ok if I could add the translations that I need, (equivalents, they're a couple of phrases not more..) I see there only Import, but no interface to add a single translation

Comment: ahh,.ok , so one entry is made for every block or interface item that I create :) nice :)

Comment: In fact, it is "for every sentences", and it is case sensitive.

Comment: However, note that t() should only be used to translate static strings. So, you shouldn't call it inside your template, but in the module that defines the block. And if you want translations for menus, blocks, taxonomies etc. created in the UI, have a look at the i18n module

Answer (score 2):

for the **t** function to work, you have to do the following:

1. enable the optional core modules called **locale** (for interface items) and optionally the **content translation** (for content).
2. grant the proper permissions for the proper roles
3. go to **site building** -> **translate interface** to access the interface translation page.

hope that helps

-peter

Comment: [Also](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/t/6#comment-1848): "It should also be noted that the string is not added to the database until it has been displayed in a language that is not the default. It is not enough to only display the string in the default language to be able to translate it via ‘Translate interface’."

Answer (score 1):

The translation is not being displayed because its not there. You need to add the translation of that particular string, only then the translated string would be rendered. If you have all the required modules in place, then you need to go to "admin/config/regional/translate/translate" and then search for your string; then click on edit and add the translation of that string.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the [Locale module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) and provide translations in the languages you want to support.